# STS.ini can't set heap more than 1024m (Eclipse configuration)

Tags: eclipse, heap-memory, ini, spring-tool-suite, low-memory

this is my sts.ini

```
-vm
C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_24/bin/javaw.exe
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.2.R36x_v20101222
-product
com.springsource.sts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
584M
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xmn128m
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-Xss1m
-XX:PermSize=128m
-XX:MaxPermSize=584m
```

My **STS**(Spring Tool Suite) **is keep falling on low memory**. I tried to increase memory of heap, but if i set -Xmx greater than 1024m (for exeample -Xmx2048m) it writes "Could not create Java Virtual Machine". I have pc with 16GB Ram and OS Windows 7 Professional 64bit and using 32bit 1.6 Java.
How can I give to my STS more memory to prevent the falling if this doesn't work. I tried to google it but I didn't find anything useful.

Comment: That is probably about the maximum you can get with a 32 bit Java. For more you need a 64 bit JVM (which means you must also use a 64 bit Eclipse/STS).

Answer (score 0):

This limitation is indeed caused by using the 32bit JVM. To use more heap space for your STS or Eclipse installation, please download the 64bit version of it and use it with a 64bit JVM for your Windows system.